# Client Server C++ Windows Application

Tags: c++, windows, client

Suppose I have 3 computers each collecting data and storing that data in files on the hard drive. I would like those computers to send those files to a 4th computer. What is the simplest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of would be to have the 4th computer advertise a shared network drive, and then have the 3 computers mount that drive as a pseudo-local drive (N:\ or whatever).  Then all the 3 computers have to do is write or copy the files onto n:\whatever_folder.  No network programming required.

Answer (score 1):

Create an FTP server on the 4th computer, and have each of the 3 data-collectors upload their files there.

How to establish an FTP server is beyond the scope of this question, or even SO.  Ask on serverfault (I think).